# How to make the program work further when an error occurs?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, parsing

I made a parser, so that when an error occurs, the parser ignores the error and starts parsing the next account. Please help me

```
     pastebin.com/qs7jW7gU
```

Comment: Please edit and put the information inside your question instead of linking to a pastebin. Please do try to make a small example, and clearly mark where the error occurs. And you probably only want to read up on exceptions and how to catch them.

Comment: What errors do you receive for what code line?

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use a try/except clause to handle errors.

It works like this:

```
try:
    [thing that could produce an error]
except:
    [thing that should run if an error has occured]
```

or

```
try:
    [thing that could produce an error]
except:
    pass
```

The second will execute nothing and the program will continue to run if an error occurs.

Comment: I have already done the second option, but the program just stops working and the cycle does not start over

Comment: Are you using `browser.close()` after you're finished with the account?

Comment: yes, but after the error appears, the program just stops working even if I added it to try and the browser does not close either

Comment: Okay, you should rewrite your question with the error clearly marked, as it's not possible to try and understand what your problem is from the link you attached.